# Whenever scrolling on my website really fast some of the content disappears or the screen flashes before loading back in after a second

Tags: html, css

Whenever I scroll really fast on this page of my website (https://raiyantech.com/Articles.html) the screen flickers white.

It only happens for this one page of my website. Also, chunks of it do not load sometimes on startup. In addition, when zooming out, the page seems to flicker white on the outside for a second before loading back in.

Basically in short when scrolling really fast or zooming out, some parts disappear for like 0.5 seconds before appearing again.

Here are the main parts of the code(Also included the head because not sure but I think it could be a misplacement of files but changing the placement did not work).

Also here is a 4-second video of me reproducing the problem:
[Short Video of Problem](https://youtube.com/shorts/ramz7LoLHOU?feature=share)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background: #0f0c29;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29) background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);
  color: white;
}

.nav-link {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(64, 0, 255) !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 1em rgb(255, 21, 0), 0 0 0.2em rgb(0, 157, 255);
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red, 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0.2em blue;
}

.col-glass-blur {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.col-glass-blur:hover {
  background-color: rgba(155, 255, 255, 0.2);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

#card {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
p,
a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Articles</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Articles.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">RaiyanTech</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="Articles.html">Articles</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="conatiner">
    <div class="col-glass-blur">
      <h1>Articles(Click to Visit)</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="card" href="programmingGuide.html">
    <div class="conatiner" id="cardContainer">
      <div class="col-glass-blur">
        <h1>Programming Guide(2022)</h1>
        <p>This article is a roadmap for learning programming. It is intended for</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a id="card" href="lucid.html">
    <div class="conatiner" id="cardContainer">
      <div class="col-glass-blur">
        <h1>About Lucid Motors</h1>
        <p>Lucid Motors is an electric car company that has faced challenges</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

I have had this issue before and I had a weird fix of putting divs with the same background color in the background with high opacities, but I tried that here and it caused another problem with the col-glass-blur container which made the text disappear and the entire screen blurred when scrolling really fast before finally loading back.

The issue is on both mobile and pc. I was wondering if it was a repaint issue or if my bootstrap files were in the wrong place.

I know it is not a browser issue or a device issue because I tested it on quite a few devices and I also tested other pages of my website and other people's website and did not experience this same issue.

I also have a footer but when I delete it the issue persists so I know it is also not the footer.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but this seems like a browser or device issue. Most likely your phone is not fast enough to keep up with the fast scrolling which makes the browser display a "empty" frame until it renders the actual content.

Comment: Yeah still not sure as I have a Samsung S22 ultra, so I do not believe speed is the problem